# Calling a service from SOAPUI timeout

Tags: java, web-services, wcf, groovy, soapui

I have problem with calling service from SOAPUI.
WSDL: [LINK](https://test.ceidg.gov.pl/CEIDG.Services.Import/RestrictionImport.svc?wsdl)

When I`m trying to call service with this settings:

[image]

I get response like this:

> The message could not be processed. This is most likely because the action 'http://tempuri.org/IRestrictionImport/AddFileToImport' is incorrect or because the message contains an invalid or expired security context token or because there is a mismatch between bindings. The security context token would be invalid if the service aborted the channel due to inactivity. To prevent the service from aborting idle sessions prematurely increase the Receive timeout on the service endpoint's binding.

When i turned off "Add default wsa:Action" i get timeout:

[image]

I need to call this service from Groovy or Java, but first i want to test it using SOAPUI.

Comment: Inspect the wsdl and read the policy, then you know what you have to do.

Comment: I read the policy but i don`t know how implement it into SOAPUI. Can You explain what should I change in SOAPUI and why to call service correct?

Comment: https://www.soapui.org/soapui-projects/ws-security.html

Comment: Are passing an attachment in the request whose name is `TEST` ?

Comment: TEST.zip is passing.

Comment: @vzamanillo I add ws-security configuration. Now my Header look this:
[link](http://paste.ofcode.org/qKCfMtwYPBgertea9tf3rB)
but the response is the same as before.